# DeprecatedWarning (cb.iterable) al usar Networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, teoría-de-grafos

Estoy intentando dibujar grafos con la librería de Networkx,pero después de crear el grafo con sus nodos y bordes uso nx.draw(G) y me dibuja el grafo pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> **The iterable function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use np.iterable instead.
>   if not cb.iterable(width):**

¿Cuál comando o que librería podría ayudarme a solucionar esto?

```
{# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# Python 3.7
# @author 3ngineer2k8

import networkx as nx # librería para usar grafos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # librería para dibujar
#import graphviz as gv

G = nx.Graph() # se crea un grafo vacío sin nodos y aristas
H = nx.path_graph(4) # 4 nodos
G.add_nodes_from(H) # lista de nodos (A,B,C,D) donde A=0 B=1 C=2 D=3
G.add_edges_from([(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0),(0,2),(1,3)]) # lista de aristas
#               ([(A,B),(B,C),(C,D),(D,A),(A,C),(B,D)]) 
#               ([(e1 ),(e2 ),(e3 ),(e4 ),(e5 ),(e6 )])
# ver cantidad de nodos y aristas
print('Cantidad de nodos:',G.number_of_nodes())
print('Cantidad de aristas:',G.number_of_edges())
# Ver nodos y aristas del grafo
print('Nodos: \n',list(G.nodes))   # ver nodos
print('Aristas: \n',list(G.edges)) # ver aristas
# ver adyacencias de los nodos
print('Adyacencias de A: \n',list(G.adj[0])) # ver adyacencias para el nodo A o 0
print('Adyacencias de B: \n',list(G.adj[1])) # ver adyacencias para el nodo B o 1
print('Adyacencias de C: \n',list(G.adj[2])) # ver adyacencias para el nodo C o 2
print('Adyacencias de D: \n',list(G.adj[3])) # ver adyacencias para el nodo D o 3
# Visualizar el grafo
nx.draw(G)  # dibujar grafo
plt.title('Grafo del mapa con 4 distritos',fontsize=16) # titulo 
plt.axis('off')  # ocultar ejes
plt.show()  # mostrar dibujo}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola  3ngineer2k8, te doy la bienvenida  a [es.so]. Debes colocar el código como texto, no como imagen. Esto facilita la lectura, la reproducción del mismo y por tanto el responder adecuadamente a tu pregunta. Para ello solo tienes que usar el botón [`editar`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/268663/edit) que hay debajo de la pregunta, copias y pegas el código en la misma, seleccionas el código recién pegado y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!. Un saludo. :D

Answer (score 1):

Parece que el código de `networkx` hace uso de un método interno de `matplotlib` llamado `cbook.iterable`, como se puede ver [aqui](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L585) en su código fuente en github,

Ese método no debería haber sido usado nunca, pues es un para uso interno de `matplotlib` y puede desaparecer cuando los desarrolladores de matplotlib lo decidan.

De hecho, han decidido eliminarlo, por lo que [desde la versión 3.1 ya hacen aparecer ese aviso](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.iterable) para que otros desarrolladores no lo usen, y en la versión 3.3 desaparecerá definitivamente.

No es algo que tú puedas arreglar. Es un problema de `networkx`, que debería dejar de usarlo y usar otra cosa en su lugar, pues de lo contrario cuando salga matplotlib 3.3 `networkx` dejará de funcionar.

Lo más que puedes hacer es reportarlo como una [*issue*](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues) para que lo cambien (ya me extraña que no esté reportado aún, pero en fin, la versión 3.1 de matplotlib es muy reciente, apenas tiene 20 días).

Otra opción que tienes es hacer un downgrade a tu matplotlib e instalar la versión 3.0 que aún no tenía ese aviso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de que otra forma podría dibujar el grafo?, existe alguna otra librería para grafos?. Saludos

Comment: Yo seguiría usando networkx sin problema, ignorando ese warning. Posiblemente muy pronto lo corregirán y te bastará con actualizar. Realmente no es razón para cambiar de librería.

Comment: Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, **no es un error o una excepción es solo un aviso (warning) porque un método ha sido marcado como *deprecated***.

Concretamente el método en cuestión es [`matplotlib.cbook.iterable`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.iterable), el cual simplemente retorna `True` o `False` en función de si el objeto pasado como argumento es o no iterable.

Los desarroladores de Matplotlib han marcado este método como deprecated en la versíon 3.1.0 liberada el 18 de Mayo del 2019 (hace muy pocos días). Esta función **va a ser reemplazada por `numpy.iterable`** en un futuro. Por este motivo se lanza el aviso, dado que **`matplotlib.cbook.iterable` será eliminada definitivamente en la futura Matplotlib 3.3**

Si estamos usando `matplotlib.cbook.iterable` en nuestro proyecto, basta con substituirla por `numpy.iterable`.

En tu caso, dado que no eres tú el que usa dicha función, sino que lo hace networkx, simplemente ignorala. **No vas a tener ningún problema hasta que no actualices a la versión 3.3 de Matplotlib**. La última versión de networkx (2.3) se lanzó un poco antes que matplotlib 3.1.0 (el 11 de abril), por lo que no tiene esto corregido.

Dado que networkx está bien mantenida  y realmente es trivial adaptar el código, es bastante probable que esté todo corregido para la próxima versión, y sin duda antes del lanzamiento de matplotlib 3.1.3

Mientras tanto, puedes:

- Instalar matplotlib 3.0.x
- Si quieres o necesitas usar la última versión de matplotlib pero te resulta molesto el warning puedes suprimirlo (temporalmente,solo hasta que se corrija el problema):

  ```
  import warnings
  from matplotlib.cbook.deprecation import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

  warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=MatplotlibDeprecationWarning)
  ```
- También puedes modificar el código del paquete  `networkx` (dado que no hay código compilado de por medio), basta con modificar el módulo `/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py`:

  - Linea 585

    ```
    if cb.iterable(edge_color) and (len(edge_color) == len(edge_pos)) \
    ```

    por:

    ```
    if np.iterable(edge_color) and (len(edge_color) == len(edge_pos)) \
    ```
  - Linea 638:

    ```
    if cb.iterable(node_size):
    ```

    por

    ```
    if np.iterable(node_size):
    ```
  - Linea 646:

    ```
    if cb.iterable(arrow_colors):
    ```

    por:

    ```
    if np.iterable(arrow_colors):
    ```
  - Linea 656:

    ```
    if cb.iterable(width):
    ```

    por

    ```
    if np.iterable(width):
    ```

## Edición

En el repositorio de GitHub se ha corregido el problema con un [commit](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/commit/eb3a675c5b2b15e33b0a4a35bcee34d6b81ed94d) aprobado el 06/06/2019. Por lo que en cuanto salga la siguiente versión, Networkx 2.4, el problema estará corregido. Si se instala el módulo desde el repositorio el problema estará corregido obviamente:

```
python -m pip install git+git://github.com/networkx/networkx.git --upgrade
```

aunque hay que tener en cuenta que **estamos instalando una versión en desarrollo** del paquete, no una estable.

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy bien explicado. Al no ser un error, esperaré las actualizaciones para no editar las librerías. Un saludo